# Laravel package html to pdf

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, type-conversion

I've used the following package for converting html to pdf:

https://github.com/vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5

But when I use this it isn't looking at all. This is my original html pdf:

[image]

And when I've convert it, it looks like this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT:

```
public function __construct(Pdf $pdf)
{
    $this->pdf = $pdf;
}
public function download()
{
    $html = view('administration.invoice')->render();
    return $this->pdf->load($html)->download();
}
```

Comment: hmm can u post your controller code?

Comment: The code is fine, just add the line to convert your relative image path to File system path that I have given you in my answer. You should insert it after the view render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This laravel package seems to be using DOMPDF which is great.

Having in mind I cannot see your code I will share the PHP code that's working for me:

```
// This should be your normal HTML page
$url = 'http://www.website.com/invoice';
$html = file_get_contents($url);

// First. Convert all relative image paths to file system paths.
// Test that the generated path is where your images files are located
$html = str_replace("/images", public_path()."/images", $html);

// Generate PDF file
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrait");
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('your_invoice_file.pdf');
```

If you also want to render a Laravel View directly to PDF replace the first two lines of code with this one

```
// Just render the view normally
$html = View::make('path/view');
```

Alternative option given the code you have added

```
$html = view('administration.invoice')->render();
$html = str_replace("/images", public_path()."/images", $html);
return $this->pdf->load($html)->download();
```

Remember to set the images folder to the one you have.

Comment: You have it working, but DOMPDF is not finding the files used to render the HTML. So Images and CSS files have to be converted to local system path.

Comment: how could I combine this with a view.blade? So instead of using the url using a view in laravel?